# How to specify a custom language parser alias for rouge in Jekyll 3?

Tags: javascript, markdown, jekyll, rouge

How does one configure Jekyll & Rouge to specify that one language
should be highlighted using the parser of another language.

For example, I want to be able to do this in my markdown source files:

````
```nodejs-repl
> foo();
Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined
```
````

... but have that code block syntax highlighted using the same
syntax highlighter Javascript language parser.

I want to do this for a couple of reasons:

1. Semantic correctness in the source files
2. Be able to run tools such as prettier and have them bypass these code blocks

Rouge already does have the concept of language aliases (see example below),
however is it possible to specify a custom language alias via Jekyll,
and if so how can this be done?

---

Details:

(1)

I am using Jekyll 3.8.5 with Rouge 3.11.0.

(2)

The following is the relevant part of my Jekyll config file:

```yaml
highlighter: rouge
```

(3)

So as to be really clear about what "language aliases" refers to,
I'll provide an example:

For Javascript, you can use both `js` and `javascript` after the code fences,
as they are language aliases by default in Rouge.
Thus, the following two code blocks are identical:

Using language alias `js`:

````
```js
foo();
```
````

Using language alias `javascript`:

````
```javascript
foo();
```
````

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to "extend" the Rogue highlighter by utilizing Jekyll's `_plugins` directory.

Much of my research came from `rogue-ruby`'s [GitHub Issue #1392](https://github.com/rouge-ruby/rouge/issues/1392) and the [source code](https://github.com/linkedin/rest.li/blob/gh-pages-source/src/_plugins/pdl_highlighter.rb) for LinkedIn's `rest-li` jekyll-based website.

## Steps

1. Create a `_plugins` directory in your Jekyll root directory
2. Create a ruby file in the `_plugins` directory
3. Use the following code to inherit the existing [Rogue Javascript code](https://github.com/rouge-ruby/rouge/blob/master/lib/rouge/lexers/javascript.rb) and "extend" (aka overwrite) the list of aliases.

```rb
# This "hook" is executed right before the site's pages are rendered
Jekyll::Hooks.register :site, :pre_render do |site|
  puts "Adding more JavaScript Markdown aliases..."
  require "rouge"

  # This class defines the PDL lexer which is used to highlight "pdl" code snippets during render-time
  class MoreJSLexer < Rouge::Lexers::Javascript
    title 'MoreJS'
    aliases 'js', 'nodejs-repl'
  end
end
```

4. Run `jekyll serve` and note the custom log line `"Adding more JavaScript Markdown aliases..."`

```
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
Adding more JavaScript Markdown aliases...
                    done in 0.637 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/Users/kueng/work/sandboxes/minima'
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

## Testing

I used the [minima](https://github.com/jekyll/minima) GitHub repository as my sandbox and `jekyll 3.8.7`.  I created a `_plugins/more_javascript.rb` Ruby file using the code in step 3.  I edited one of the markdown files with the markdown snippet below and noticed only `js` and `nodejs-repl` had syntax highlighting.

````
```nodejs
var a, b, c;
a = 5; b = 6; c = a + b;
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = c;
```
```js
var a, b, c;
a = 5; b = 6; c = a + b;
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = c;
```
```nodejs-repl
var a, b, c;
a = 5; b = 6; c = a + b;
document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = c;
```
````

Comment: Hey @Kin this looks like it is a viable solution... however, I have a feeling that it may not work on Github pages thanks to its employment of custom Ruby code. I'm aware now that I didn't specify Github pages in my original question - just wanted to check if you have had any luck with that/ any ideas around that?

Comment: Hey @bguiz.  In my experience with GitHub pages, I don't see any major blockers with my approach with custom Ruby code.  However, I only have experience with use a CI/CD tool (e.g. TravisCI) to handle the build step for Jekyll-based websites.  What TravisCI will do is run `jekyll build` and push the `_site` directory to a branch (e.g. `gh-pages`) used by GitHub pages.  I've also ran `jekyll build` and used a manual `git push` to `gh-pages` branch.  I ran `jekyll build` on my example above and noticed that the RAW html only adds `class=highlighter-rouge` to the `js` and `nodejs-repl` sections.

Comment: Con't.  Since the raw HTML is showing the expected Rogue styling on the new custom `nodejs-repl`, I suspect the only unknown from getting my solution to work is how GitHub handles `jekyll build` process.  My experience predates all the new GitHub CI/CD tools.  I did find some supporting documentation about the `_plugins` Jekyll directory here https://jekyllrb.com/docs/continuous-integration/github-actions/#control-over-gemset

Comment: Yeah makes sense. I've just tried this out locally in my repo - no Github pages involved yet - and the plugin doesn't appear to trigger at all. I don't even get the `Adding more JavaScript Markdown aliases...` from the `puts`, which is strange. EDIT: this is my Gemfile: https://gist.github.com/bguiz/f585e0cd4b5c4777283e3eb74749101c

Comment: In my testing, I did _not_ specify any highlighter in `_config.yml`.  I let Jekyll default to Rogue.  I normally run jekyll 4.0, so I had to create a `Gemfile` to downgrade the `minima` code sandbox to Jekyll 3.x.  The `Gemfile` only had `gem "jekyll", "~> 3.8.5"` and `gem "minima"`.  I used `bundle install` and `bundle exec jekyll s` to run the `minima` sandbox.

Comment: Hey @kin I got this working, thank you very much. Turns out the issue was that the github pages gem was interfering with this (and any other plugin not on its whitelist), and once I figured that out, it started working locally. Getting this to work on github pages is still a work in progress, however. Anyway, bounty goes to you!